# How to properly use `after_commit`?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a huge model with a bunch of `after_commit` callbacks.

```
  after_commit :a, on: [:create, :update]
  after_commit :b, on: :create
  after_commit :c, on: :create
  after_commit :d, on: [:create, :update]
  after_commit :e, on: :destroy
  after_commit :f, on: :destroy
```

The problem is for some reason, sometimes my callback on `:create` doesn't run, in spite of saving a record in this db.

I am suspecting one of the callback raised an exception which caused the other callbacks to not execute. (Or could there be any other reason? )

How can I write my callback in a way that executes even if some other callbacks failed to get executed?

Comment: If one of the callbacks raised an exception that you should see the exception. In the context of a Rails application, the user would see a 500 error page and the exception and its stack trace should be logged. Are there any entries in your log file that support your assumption? How do you handle errors in your application currently?

Answer (score 0):

See here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html#transaction-callbacks

If a callback fails within a transaction, the remaining will not execute.

Instead, make sure you handle the exception entirely in your callback method:

```
def a
   begin
   # try to do the action
   rescue
   # if you code fails it will go here, and you should clean it up appropriately
   ensure
   # something that will always execute, pass or fail
   end
end
```